# Reflection of data

Tags: c#, reflection, private-methods

How do I get any object and its private field read and then returned

```
public class Person
{
    private string _password;


    }

    public string Name { get; set }

    public Gender man { get; set }

    public int Age { get; set }
}
```

Here is the class from which you have to get the data

Comment: You need to put stuff in `ReadPrivateField` i'm guessing :)

Comment: If you are asking whether you can get the backing field to a property, you can only do it with an auto implemented property, otherwise it could be anything, Even then this could be hit or miss im thinking

Comment: Okay, and how do I do that? Look update.

Comment: `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static` -- that's looking for a static field, but your `_password` field is an instance field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple. You need to get the type of your target object with `typeof` or `GetType()` if you have an instance like in this case. Then you can use `GetField` to get the desired field. But there is a catch. `GetField` by default only search for fields that are public and non-static. TO chage that you need to give it some `BindingFlags`. An Example:

```cs
public static string ReadPrivateField(object obj, string fieldName)
{
    var type = obj.GetType();
    // NonPublic = obly search for private fields.
    // Instance = only search for non-static fields.
    var field = type.GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    return field.GetValue(obj) as string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First get the object `Type`, the get its non public instance fields with the given name.
You can then get the value from the object. Example:

```
public static string ReadPrivateField<T>(T obj, string fieldName)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var field = type.GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var value = field.GetValue(obj);
    return value as string;
}
```